# Return a response object from http get in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to angular and I've been trying to use http.get to get data from an API and assign it to a value in a component

This is the method which is used to get data

```
  public getByUserName(username:String):User{

     let res:CommonResponse;

     this.http.get<CommonResponse>(BASE_URL+'/'+username)
    .subscribe(  (response) => { res = response },
      error => this.errorHandler.handleError(error)
    )
    console.log("Response "+ res)
    return res.responseObj;
  }
```

When I print the result inside the subscribe function I get the result

But when I've tried to assign it to a local variable and return responseObj from res.

but the res object is undefined.
Is there any other way to archive this functionality

Comment: You can't reach data outside of subscribe .it is async

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this with Observables without using promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you dont get any response is that all the HTTP method is async

You have two options to handle the problem

Use the observable provided by angular on itself

```
let res:ReplaySubject<CommonResponse>=new ReplaySubject(); 

public getByUserName(username:String):User{    
    this.http.get<CommonResponse>(BASE_URL+'/'+username)
    .subscribe(  (response) => { this.res.next(response) },
      error => this.errorHandler.handleError(error)
    )
  }
```

and then you can use the res REplaySubject to subscribe in your component.

Or if you are not really familiar with RxJs and Observables/ReplaySubject a simpler method is to convert the request to a promise and use `await`

```
public async getByUserName(username:String):User{
     let res:CommonResponse;    
     res= await this.http.get<CommonResponse>(BASE_URL+'/'+username).toPromise()
          .catch((error)=>{
              this.errorHandler.handleError(error)
                 })
      console.log("Response "+ res)
      return res.responseObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your console/return statement inside the subscribe like this:

```
public getByUserName(username:String):User{
this.http.get<CommonResponse>(BASE_URL+'/'+username).subscribe(  (response) => {
  console.log("Response "+ res);
  return res.responseObj;
},
error => this.errorHandler.handleError(error)
```

);

Your function won't wait for the subscribe to complete because it's asynchronous. That's why it's undefined when you try to access responseObj outside the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should return res.responseObj within the subscribe method.
Or you can try -

```
 public getByUserName(username:String):User{

 let res:CommonResponse;

 return this.http.get<CommonResponse>(BASE_URL+'/'+username)
.subscribe(  (response) => { res = response.responseObj },
  error => this.errorHandler.handleError(error)
)
```

}